# Submit button - Change CSS of submit button once no longer disabled

Tags: html, css, forms, input, submit

Inside my form, after the user has entered all the required fields (green check marks appear in input fields) and the submit button is no longer 'disabled', I would like my submit button to have orange text and a white background as it appears in the attached image instead of the gray background and black text that it looks like presently.  Does anyone know if there is a way to change this?

[image: Submit Button]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvffpjxb/6/)

```js
function phoneNumber(phone) {
  var phoneno = /^\d{9}|\d{10}|\d{11}$/;

  console.log("PHONE: " + phoneno.test(phone));
  return phoneno.test(phone);
}

$('input[type="tel"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#phone')) {
      if (phoneNumber($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
        $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-times-circle-o").addClass("fa-check-circle");
      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
        console.log("this works");
        $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-times-circle-o");
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      console.log("this works")
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
    console.log("this works")

  }
});


function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  console.log("email: " + re.test(email));
  return re.test(email);
}

$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#email')) {
      if (validateEmail($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
        $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-times-circle-o").addClass("fa-check-circle");

      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
        console.log("this works 1")
        $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-times-circle-o");
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      console.log("this works 2");
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
    console.log("this works 3");
  }
});


test = function() {
  if ($("#first_name").val() &&
    $("#last_name").val() &&
    $("#email").val() &&
    $("#phone").val() &&
    $("#city").val() &&
    $("#state").val() &&
    $("#company").val()) {

    $("#sub").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f78e2a;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f78e2a;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lato;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Lato";
  letter-spacing: 70px;
}

input[type="tel"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

textarea:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#co {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

label:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

select,
label {
  height: 50px;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 2% 1%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Lato";
}

#sub {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #B9B9B9;
  color: #959595;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  display: block;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #f78e2a;
}

@media (max-width: 426px) {
  label {
    width: 98%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 426px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-self: flex-start;
  }
}

label {
  position: relative;
}

.fa {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -5%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s, color .5s;
}

[data-valid] .fa {
  opacity: 1;
  color: green;
}

[data-valid="valid"] .fa {
  color: green;
}

[data-valid="error"] .fa {
  color: red;
}

.error {
  display: none;
  color: red;
  font-size: .7em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(150%);
}

[data-valid="error"] .error {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="container" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
  <label>First Name
                    <input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </label>
  <label>Last Name
                    <input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </label>
  <label>Email
                    <span class="error">Please enter a valid email address</span>
                    <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </label>
  <label>Phone
                    <span class="error">Please enter a valid phone number</span>              
                    <input id="phone" maxlength="80" name="phone" size="20"    type="tel" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </label>
  <label>City
                    <input id="city" name="city" maxlength="40" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </label>
  <label>State/Province
                    <input id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </label>
  <label id="co">Company
                    <input id="company" name="company" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </label>
  <label>Comments
                    <textarea id="comments" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" onkeyup="test()"></textarea>
                    <input id="sub" type="submit" disabled="disabled" />
                  </label>

  <div>
    <select hidden="true" id="00N6A000008yXMN" name="00N6A000008yXMN" title="Product Interest">
                        <option value="">--None--</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="Visiant">Visiant</option>
                        <option  value="Tessellate">Tessellate</option>
                    </select><br>

    <select hidden="true" id="lead_source" name="lead_source">
                        <option value="">--None--</option>
                        <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
                    <option value="Trade Show">Trade Show</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="Website">Website</option>
                    <option value="Direct Marketing">Direct Marketing</option>
                    <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select><br>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Use `input[disabled]{ /* your style for disabled input*/}` or `input:not([disabled]){/* style for not disabled input*/}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done only with CSS:

Customize the CSS attributes as you want in those two rules.

```
#sub{  /* enabled */
  background-color:white;
  color:orange;
}
#sub:disabled{  /* disabled */
  background-color:grey;
  color:black;
}
```

Comment: thank you that was easy! Here is the fiddle in case any needs it: http://jsfiddle.net/vvffpjxb/10/

Answer (score 0):

@Louys answered your question on a basic level, but you may want to check your CSS.  For example, you are trying to style a  element, when you have your submit button as an  element, so it doesn't properly associate the two. Beyond that, your jQuery is incorrectly modifying the state of the button.

You should update your CSS to do the following:

```
#sub {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#sub:disabled {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #B9B9B9;
  color: #959595;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  display: block;
}

#sub:focus,
#sub:not(:disabled) {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #f78e2a;
}
```

Note what I do here, and how I'm targeting the element you want to change. Before, you were targeting a  element, but your submit button was actually an  element. This is enough to throw the browser for a loop. Just be careful to check your CSS selectors. Also, I modified your Javascript to be a little bit more dutiful:

```
test = function() {
      if
      (
        $("#first_name").parent().attr('data-valid') == 'valid'
        && $("#last_name").parent().attr('data-valid') == 'valid'
        && $("#email").parent().attr('data-valid') == 'valid'
        && $("#phone").parent().attr('data-valid') == 'valid'
    && $("#city").parent().attr('data-valid') == 'valid'
    && $("#state").parent().attr('data-valid') == 'valid'
    && $("#company").parent().attr('data-valid') == 'valid'
  )
  {
    $("#sub").prop("disabled", false);
  }
  else
  {
    $("#sub").prop('disabled', true);
  }
}
```

Check out the Fiddle for all of the changes I've made to help this code be a little more effective: http://jsfiddle.net/vvffpjxb/11/

Notice that I've changed the way you check for values, and that it's targeting the correct elements. That's what was going wrong; you just needed to target the right elements, in the right way. Also, I added the ability for the button to be disabled again, should any of the fields become invalid.